# Why does C# Process.Start not find the executable on my path?

Tags: c#, windows

I have this folder on my windows Path environment variable: C:\bin

I have a tool named 7z inside C:\bin\7z\7z.exe.

If I open any shell, like Powershell I can run the command "7z" and it works fine, the executable is found and it runs (And `where.exe 7z` prints out C:\bin\7z\7z.exe). The fact that the executable is inside a folder named after itself doesn't get in the way of the executable being found. The folder and the executable inside the folder seem to have to be named exactly as the program I am trying to run.

However, when running code in C# to run the executable, it is not found.

```
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    FileName = "7z",
    Arguments = $"-h",
  };
  var p = Process.Start(startInfo); // Throws
```

I know that Process.Start supports Path environment variables here as I can successfully run this code for other executables that are not in inner folders.

My questions are:

- Why isn't Process.Start able to find the executable?
- Is having a directory named after the executable a supported and documented way to find executables with a Path directory? Where can I read this documentation?

Comment: An extra detail: If I set "UseShellExecute" as true, then this actually opens the directory C:\bin\7z, which indicates to me that it is trying to execute the folder and not the executable 7z.exe inside the folder. That's my hunch. How can I get it to automatically find and run the 7z.exe?

Comment: Yes, it works in cmd.exe as well

Comment: Yikes okay I think I've narrowed down the issue.

There's 2 Path variables, one for my user and one for the system. The system one does in fact have C:\bin\7z. The C# program doesn't seem to use this system path variable..

Comment: Shouldn't this be `FileName = "7z.exe"`?

Comment: That seems to not work either.

Comment: `C:\bin` and `C:\bin\7z` are different directories. It's not obvious why you expect the system to guess that you meant the latter when you instructed it to search the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` to false, you must supply the full path to your executable. In this case Process.Start will call the [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) function. From the documentation:

> The string can specify the full path and file name of the module to execute or it can specify a partial name. In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification. The function will not use the search path. This parameter must include the file name extension; no default extension is assumed.

If you use `ShellExecute` true, the shell's best guest for **7z** will be the directory, as you dont supply the .exe extension.